# Use justify-content: flex-end and to have vertical scrollbar

Tags: css, flexbox

I have chat and I need to scroll all content to bottom.
I want to use justify-content: flex-end and to have vertical scrollbar.

```css
.session-textchat {
  height: 320px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 83.92%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver,
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 47px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver .message,
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender .message {
  position: relative;
  padding: 17px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver {
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver .message {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #535353;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender {
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender .message {
  background: url('../img/rgbapng/0050ff26.png');
  background: rgba(0, 80, 255, 0.15);
  color: #0050ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="session-textchat">
  <div class="past-messages">
    <div class="receiver">
      <span class="message">
            Good afternoon David. Welcome to your appointment! How are you today?
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="sender">
      <span class="message">
            Hello doctor. I feel terrible to be honest.
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="receiver">
      <span class="message">
            I can see from your notes that you've been having some ear ache - can you tell me a bit more about your symptoms?
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="sender">
      <span class="message">
            Hello doctor. I feel terrible to be honest.
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="receiver">
      <span class="message">
            I can see from your notes that you've been having some ear ache - can you tell me a bit more about your symptoms?
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/egzdhmgr/).

Is it possible? Or please give me better solution.

Comment: You need to be able to scroll to bottom or to always have the content scrolled to bottom?

Comment: for your parent container use display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; overflow-y: auto; and remove flex-end from your child container.

Comment: @Ibartolic answer works well and is simple.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I just had to face this issue myself and, after concluding [it is](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151) a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=411624), I came up with a workaround.

In summary, don't use `justify-content: flex-end` but rather put a `margin-top: auto` on the first child. Unlike flex-end this doesn't break the scrollbar functionality, and it bottom-aligns the contents when they're not overflowing the container.

Example based on @SrdjanDejanovic's fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/peter9477/4t5r0t5b/

In case the example isn't available, here's the relevant CSS:

```
#container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    /* justify-content: flex-end; DO NOT USE: breaks scrolling */
}
#container > :first-child {
    margin-top: auto !important;
    /* use !important to prevent breakage from child margin settings */
}
```

An alternative workaround that I believe I've also used is to add an extra container for the scrollbar. Use the flex-end on the inner container and have the outer container handle the scrolling. I generally dislike workarounds that require adding dummy elements though, so I prefer my CSS-only solution above.

Comment: Just noticed that this is a copy of my answer. What is the difference?

Comment: @lbartolic A copy? Not really... In fact there seems little in common between them. I certainly did not read yours before posting mine (that's not how I roll), and mine includes some links to background that yours does not (gathered after extensive research, I might add), and the margin-top part that's probably crucial to my answer isn't in yours, so they may have some small parts the same but they're clearly not.

Comment: I think 'maring-top: auto' is a good approach but works till we reach the height at which there is no space left at top, so margin auto doesn't help, e.g. scroll starts appearing. I had to apply manual scroll with scrollTop = scrollHeight to achieve the always  scrolled bottom position.

Comment: This solution even works well with the infamous [FireFox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042151) and [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/108). So, instead of `flex-direction`, using `flex-flow` and `margin-top` for some mysterious reason works.

Comment: Isn't `!important`, like, an anti-pattern? Can't the problem be solved without resorting to it? Did not read too thouroughly, but the jsfiddle from this answer does not seem to work anymore, the scroll starts from top in Chromium 94.

Comment: This worked great. Note: for Tailwind folks, it's `first:mt-auto`.

Comment: Interestingly the FF issue says it is `RESOLVED FIXED`, but I've just encountered this issue today in an up to date version...

Comment: `#container::before{content: ''; display: block; margin-top: auto; }` is better than `!important`

Comment: This solution works. However, content will be scrolled to the top when the scrollbar shows. Still need to figure out how to get the content to start scrolled to the bottom, like it would with `flex-end`, hopefully without JS.

Answer (score 57):

Probably you've already solved this, but I faced this problem too and found a solution by trial and error, so I'm going to share it.

Having parent container's display set to flex `display: flex` and child's items align to flex-end `align-items: flex-end` will prevent `overflow-y: auto` to work.

Instead, you can leave you can use next CSS properties for your parent container (in your case `session-textchat`):

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse; /* 'column' for start, 'column-reverse' for end */
overflow-y: scroll; /* or overflow-y: auto ... */
```

This will make your child div appear on the bottom of parent container (it will act like `flex-end`) and enable vertical scroll if content height is bigger than parent container.

**I made a little jsfiddle for you if this sounds confusing:**
https://jsfiddle.net/lbartolic/9od4nruy/3/

In jsfiddle you can see header part, content part and footer. Container has fixed height and each part takes required height to fill the container. Content part `_b__content` will be scrollable if its content is taller than `_b__content`'s height.

I hope this will help someone.
Cheers.

Comment: Finally, the only answer that got this right, without saying it's a bug. You did not address the sender/receiver alignment, which can be solved with a simple property `align-self` on each class.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I focused on aligning main containers (header/content/footer).

Comment: The jsfiddle does not work on Safari 9.1.1.  The scrollbar does not show up.

Comment: The jsfiddle also fails in Firefox 50.0.2 - The scrollbar shows up, but it's grayed out.

Comment: This only seems to work on Chrome and Safari (11.0) but not in Firefox nor IE.

Comment: adding 'min-height: 0;' on child will show the scrollbar in Firefox

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that the content is now in the inverse order, from bottom to top. Still a bug 7 years later!

Comment: column-reverse didn't work for me since I need them in normal order, so margin-top answer really saved the day for me.

Answer (score 21):

Also There is also another Solution

Remove the `justify-content` and add `flex: 1 1 auto;` property to the first element(`create an empty div`)

#### Old

HTML

```
<div class="content-reversed">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-reversed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

#### New

HTML

```
<div class="content-reversed">
  <div class="fix"></div> //add this dummy div
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-reversed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content-reversed .fix {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
 }
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work when the scrollbar appears, i.e. when the scrollbar appears I also want the messages to keep staying at the bottom

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be a common bug among the browsers.

You should distribute your style onto 2 containers: the outer will be scrolled, and the inner will be a flex container. Also, you need some js to keep your message list scrolled to bottom while adding new messages.

Here is an example of code:

**markup**:

```html
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='inner-scroll'>
        <div id='inner-flex'>
            <div class='flex-item'>Item 1</div>
            <div class='flex-item'>Item 2</div>
            ...
        </div>
</div>
```

**style**:

```css
#inner-scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#inner-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-item { /*nothing*/ }
```

**JS**:

```js
function messagePushCallback()
{
    var scrollable=document.getElementById('inner-scroll');
    scrollable.scrollTo(0, scrollable.scrollHeight-scrollable.clientHeight);
}

// for an example
chat.onMessagePush(messagePushCallback);

window.addEventListener('load', messagePushCallback);
```

In JS, `scrollable.scrollHeight` shows the whole height of the element, including the space beyond its visible part, while `scrollable.clientHeight` is for the height of the visible part.

Comment: This solution works in both Firefox 57 and Chrome 63. The current most upvoted answer (using `column-reverse` instead of `flex-end`) doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn `.session-textchat` into a flex *column* then `margin-top: auto` on `.past-messages` to send it to the bottom. Then play with `overflow-y: scroll` and some jQuery:

```js
function updateScroll() {
  $("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chat').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
}
updateScroll();
$("#send_button").on('click', updateScroll);
```

```css
.session-textchat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages {
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver,
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 47px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver .message,
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender .message {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver {
  text-align: left;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .receiver .message {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #535353;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender {
  text-align: right;
}
.session-textchat .past-messages .sender .message {
  background: url("../img/rgbapng/0050ff26.png");
  background: rgba(0, 80, 255, 0.15);
  color: #0050ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="chat" class="session-textchat">
    <div class="past-messages">
      <div class="receiver">
        <span class="message">
        Good afternoon David. Welcome to your appointment! How are you today?
      </span>
      </div>
      <div class="sender">
        <span class="message">
        Hello doctor. I feel terrible to be honest.
      </span>
      </div>
      <div class="receiver">
        <span class="message">
        I can see from your notes that you've been having some ear ache - can you tell me a bit more about your symptoms?
      </span>
      </div>
      <div class="sender">
        <span class="message">
        Hello doctor. I feel terrible to be honest.
      </span>
      </div>
      <div class="receiver">
        <span class="message">
        I can see from your notes that you've been having some ear ache - can you tell me a bit more about your symptoms?
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="msg"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button href="#" id="send_button" class="btn btn-success">Send message</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Look at this **full-screen [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egzdhmgr/7/embedded/result/)**.

Comment: The best answer ever! `margin-top: auto` did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
justify-content: flex-start;
```

Comment: This solution does work. The problem is now content logic has to use prepends instead of appends. That can get really confusing fast for apps like chat where this type of view is needed.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against my table for a bit, I came up with this solution:

Using column-reverse in the parent element gives you the desired effect, BUT will reverse the order of your items, which is problematic. To mitigate this problem, simply add a wrapper class and element to hold the items you wish to scroll.

Here is an example:

```css
.scrolling-parent {
  height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-wrapper {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-parent">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help anyone who encounters this obscure bug!