# Flex div does not show overflow scrollbars

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flex container with standard divs in it. The problem is that it never shows a scroller for overflow. I would like it to scroll vertically. I am just typing more words so I can submit this question.

```css
#chatBody {
  height: 170px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatBody">
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use justify-content: flex-end and to have vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130760/use-justify-content-flex-end-and-to-have-vertical-scrollbar)

Comment: `justify-content` is the culprit in your case. Try removing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#chatBody {
    height: 80px;
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 0;
    flex-direction: column-reverse; /* 'column' for start, 'column-reverse'       for end */
}
```

```html
<div id="chatBody">
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div><div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
<div class="chat-msg">
    <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
    <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I used flex-direction column-reverse instead of justify-content because justify-content prevents overflow from working. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Looks like you are following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776769/2767755) answer. If you think that answer is correct mark it as duplicate here by linking it

Comment: @ArupRakshit Max answered my question and solved the issue, and it will help other people. I wish StackOverflow was less about marking duplicates and more about solving and answering questions.

Comment: You should check with firefox, mine(latest /w7) do not allow scrolling :( (column:okay/column-reverse:bug)

Comment: @jozenbasin What max answered is mentioned in the linked SO answer. He took the answer as a reference... When we see any question is already answered, we link it for future readers only. If you take the time, and have a look at the answer you would figure this out. Max took the answer from SO post without even changing a single word. I don;t know why he puts so much effort when it is there already.

Comment: @ArupRakshit What are you talking about? My answer took me no time at all, I had already known of this issue. I am just trying to help out Jozenbasin

Answer (score 2):

To **avoid**`(not cure)` the bug of the scroll being inactive with `column-reverse` you should use an extra `flex`*(or not)* container wrapping it.

Once you used `column-reverse` the last element will be shown first at top and the scrollbar will be working where needed on the parent wrapper.

To finally get that last element **visually at the bottom** , you can mirror the whole container via `scale()` and  mirror again each children so it is readable again .

**NOTE:** scrolling will be reversed ,scrolling the wheel down will be scrolling up at screen... it is mirrored.

demo below

```css
#chatBody {
  height: auto;/* reset */
  width: auto;/* reset */
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;/* reset preparing instead justify-content flex-end */
  transform: scale(1, 1);/* reset, children 1 after 1 will be set back to readable */
  counter-reset:div;/* demo purpose */
}
.chat-msg:before {
counter-increment:div;
content:counter(div)' - ';
float:left;color:red;
}
div[id] {
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid;
  height: 170px;
  flex-flow: column;
}

div[id],
.chat-msg {
  transform: scale(1, -1);/* visual mirroring */
}

.chat-msg {
  border-top: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id>
  <div id="chatBody">
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-msg">
      <div class="chat-msg-room"></div>
      <div class="chat-msg-user">last</div>
      <div class="chat-msg-text">Disconnected from chat</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do not want to mirror the container, this [answer uses a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130760/use-justify-content-flex-end-and-to-have-vertical-scrollbar#37350329) so the scroll is already all the way to the bottom and there is no need to involve the flex model.

Comment: Thanks, but Max's answer was a one-liner and worked for me

Comment: @jozenbasin you are welcome, i'm surprised cause his snippet does not scroll with my firefox ? did i misunderstand the question ? edit: Max's answer does work with chrome, not FF :(