# Chat Box UI not scrolling with react-bootstrap Accordion

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am creating chat box UI with `react-bootstrap` and using `Accordion` for it. However, when messages are overflow from container height of `50vh` its not behave to scroll.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-fire-qix83?file=/src/App.js:0-3039)

#### Expected Behavior

Scrolling behavior should be achieved

#### Actual Behavior

Its not scrolling when messages overflow. I have also added `overflow-y: scroll` to container div.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-fire-qix83?file=/src/App.js:0-3039)

```
import React from "react";
import Accordion from "react-bootstrap/Accordion";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem, quas."
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      from: "Jash Jariwala",
      to: "me",
      text:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, aperiam iure atque exercitationem ab ducimus."
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      from: "Jash Jariwala",
      to: "me",
      text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing."
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      from: "me",
      to: "Jash Jariwala",
      text: "Hi, How Are You ?"
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="PopMessageBox-wrapper">
      <Accordion>
        <Card>
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Message
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              <div className="read-message-wrapper">
                {messages.length ? (
                  messages.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <div
                        key={item.id}
                        className={
                          item.from === "me"
                            ? "message-item float-right"
                            : "message-item"
                        }
                        id={item.id}
                      >
                        {item.from === "me" ? (
                          <span></span>
                        ) : (
                          <p style={{ color: "black" }}>From: {item.from}</p>
                        )}

                        <h6 style={{ color: "black" }}>{item.text}</h6>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                  <span>No Messages. Start Chatting ...</span>
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="send-message-wrapper"></div>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with regards to your `.read-message-wrapper` element that has `justify-content: flex-end`. Comment that out and you will see that the `overflow` property works as expected. Regarding why it does not work you can refer to: [Use justify-content: flex-end and to have vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36130760/8680805).

With regards to the chat scroll position initializing at the bottom, I solved this in the past by updating the HTMLElement `scrollTop` each time a message state has updated (e.g., a new message is received or sent - note that this should technically trigger on-mount as well since the state is initialized). The formula I used is as follows:

```
$0.scrollTop = $0.scrollHeight - $0.clientHeight // where $0 is your element with overflow property
```